# Replacing values in Pandas DataFrame based on condition

Tags: pandas, if-statement, iteration

Let's say I have a `df` dataframe and I want to iterate through the columnn `df['Social Distancing Advisory']` and replace the `str` `"sah"` by  `"1"` and `"sip"` by `"0"`.

I do know that it is generally not encouraged to iterate with `for` loops with Pandas DataFrames, but for the sake of understanding, let's say I want to do so.

---

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_excel('/Users/Arthur/Desktop/COVID-RA/state_data.xlsx')

for row in df['Social Distancing Advisory']:

  if df['Social Distancing Advisory'] == 'sah':
    df['Social Distancing Advisory'].replace('sah','1')
    
  if df['Social Distancing Advisory'] == 'sip':    
    df['Social Distancing Advisory'].replace('sip','0')
```

`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

**EDIT**

1. Least Efficient way (**NOT RECOMMENDED**): looping over both columns and manually replacing each value if they meet the condition -that is if they are `sah` or `sip`

```
for row in df['Social Distancing Advisory']:

   if row == 'sah':
      row = "1"

   elif row == "sip":
      row = "0"
```

2. Most Efficient way: boolean indexing with `df.iloc`

```
df.iloc[df['Social Distancing Advisory'] == 'sah', 'Social Distancing Advisory'] = '1'
df.iloc[df['Social Distancing Advisory'] == 'sip', 'Social Distancing Advisory'] = '0'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to iterate for replacing strings. Here is an example.

```
    import pandas as pd 
    df = pd.read_excel('/Users/Arthur/Desktop/COVID-RA/state_data.xlsx')
    df['Social Distancing Advisory'] = df['Social Distancing Advisory'].replace('sah',1)
    df['Social Distancing Advisory'] = df['Social Distancing Advisory'].replace('sip',0)
    print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the `ValueError` because `df['Social Distancing Advisory'] == 'sah'` statement gives a series of boolean values - `True` for those indices where value matches `'sah'`, `False` otherwise. This is exactly what the error message reads.

Following code can solve the problem using [`pd.Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html?highlight=replace#pandas.Series.replace) method by providing mapping of required changes

```py
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_excel('/Users/Arthur/Desktop/COVID-RA/state_data.xlsx')

df['Social Distancing Advisory'] = df['Social Distancing Advisory'].replace({
    "sah": "1",
    "sip": "0"
})
```